Ran a Run Environment cell and got this error?
I'm working with Deep Exemplar-based Video colorisation demo on Colab. Worked for two years till sunday. I've copied the opening code after it ran successfully vs the opening error flag after i tried running it today.
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting torch==1.6.0
Downloading torch-1.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (748.8 MB)
|████████████████████████████████| 748.8 MB 18 kB/s
Collecting torchvision==0.7.0
Downloading torchvision-0.7.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.9 MB)
versus now
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.6.0 (from versions: 1.11.0, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.5.0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.6.0
I ran the program and it failed to download  - torch-1.6.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
